# Navigation Bar not visible swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

i am trying to set `navigationBar` in xcode programmatically with swift 4. I also want back button with title to appear too.

After my logic, nothing seems to appear on my app. I dont know what am not getting right. Please help.

```
import UIKit

class SellBaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.setNavigationBar()
           setLayout()

    }

    func reload() {
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func setNavigationBar() {
        let width = self.view.frame.width
        let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 44))
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar);
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Navigation bar")
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(selectorX))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBtn
        navigationBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
    }

    func setLayout(){

    }
   @objc func selectorX() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `SellBaseViewController` embedded into `UINavigationController`? If not - it have to.

Comment: how do i do so with code?

Comment: Would you show the code which instantiates `SellBaseViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in viewWillAppear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setNavigationBar()
           setLayout()
```